# Issue with ng-repeat after calling $compile to bind dynamic HTML in angular

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, razor

I'm building an application which has multiple tabs containing HTML which is generated dynamically. Clicking a tab calls a .net MVC controller to render a razor view, return the HTML to the angular and display in the body of the tab.

The body of the tab needs to be bound to an underlying angular model. I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, but this is what I have so far, which mostly works:

```
function updateHtml(html, tabId) {
        angular.element(document.getElementById('tabBodyContainer')).html(html);
        $scope.currentTab = tabId;
        var fnLink = $compile(document.getElementById('tabBodyContainer'));     // returns a Link function used to bind template to the scope
        fnLink($scope);
    }
```

This works great except when I click on a tab which has a repeater. My first tab has a repeater which renders fine on load because the first tab is generated on page load by the razor view engine and then bound. When I click a different tab and click back, all the rows in my repeater are missing, as if the repeater didn't bind or the DOM never updated for that section after the $compile.

Any ideas? Or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: This is completely the wrong way to use angular. Your MVC app should be nothing more than a data api and shouldn't be rendering partials. In your angular code there is no reason to be doing dom manipulation yourself for basic view rendering. Suggest you study some basic angular tutorials

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out - I was caching the HTML so that I only called my MVC controller once per tab. The HTML for the first tab was being cached AFTER angular had been bound, meaning the HTML that was added on tab 1 was post compile HTML. 
For most html this is fine, however with repeaters, angular replaces the markup with the  comments before, meaning if I cache that HTML it won't know what was supposed to be repeated the next time I insert that HTML and run the $compile